# How do you add a screenshot image to your Stack Overflow post?

Tags: discussion, design

How do you add a screenshot image to your Stack Overflow question?

Answer (score 48):

In your toolbar when typing a question you just click the button above (typical image-button with landscape in a frame), then simply just drag to upload a picture, or paste the URL to one if you're hosting it elsewhere.

[image: answer form]

You  can also type the following to embed a image. The syntax is called [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). Here is more information to help you with the [formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

```
   [![image description][1]][1]

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7zys.png
```

Comment: This also works then `![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7zys.png)`.

Comment: @Friedrich's comment is great, but note that adding 'alternative text' in [] is kind toward people who use assistive technology (or need translation). So if only you can always describe the photo in a few words, like this:  `![description what is in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7zys.png)`

Comment: Just note that there must be a blank line between the markdown shown and other content